# not able to stop VxWorks auto-boot

Tags: boot, vxworks

I am trying to repair a Keysight N9320B spectrum analyzer that is stuck at boot presumably due to firmware upgrade going wrong...
I have accessed the instrument boot prompt and tRootTask at some point stops due to some "undefined instruction" exception
Now I am trying to stop the auto boot so I can set up the boot loader to read the vxworks from tftp
however there is no way to stop it. It goes right to auto boot and does not show a message like "press any key to stop auto booting" or something like that. I have tried all sorts of key press with highest speed possible...any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

The normal way to interrupt would be to press "any key" in the short window between the bootloader starting, and it starting to load the VxWorks runtime kernel.

This would normally be by pressing a key on a keyboard (or via a serial connection).
You might try connecting a usb keyboard, and see if you can get it to stop